# EMails bouncing in Outlook due to remembered quotes on email address

Tags: microsoft-outlook

I have the following problem:

- I receive a forwarded email
- The original senders email address is only available as a mailto: link in the original email
- I copy the mailto link to use as the to address on a new email.
- The new email bounces because of quotes that were added to the email address.
- Now whenever I try to send to this email again (even if I type the address without quotes), Outlook remembers the quotes and the email bounces.

I'm using Outlook 2010

Is there a solution to this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Microsoft hotfix at http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2597052 addresses this issue

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like Outlook is just remembering the bad email address in its Autocomplete.  You should just be able to start typing the address, and hit Delete while the bad address is highlighted.  Then re-type the whole address correctly, and Outlook will remember that one from now on.